# looking for one word to say "doing lots of work but in vain"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that means "doing lots of work but in vain"

the amount of work done is a lot, but the results obtained is very small.

Comment: Unless this is poetry, it should be **vain** (not vein).

Comment: As an aside, meeting the quality standards for SE sites is not *that* difficult. You just need to know what the quality standards are first, which is *more* difficult, but hardly a task requiring you to reach into greek mythology to find an appropriate metaphor.

Comment: This type of request has been asked again and again. There must be a way that visitors can find the answer immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A phrase you could use is "Sisyphean task/job/cycle", or simply "Sisyphean" as an adjective.

> In Greek mythology, Sisyphus was punished for his self-aggrandizing craftiness and deceitfulness by being forced to roll an immense boulder up a hill only for it to roll down when they near the top, repeating this action for eternity. [[source]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sisyphus)

Therefore, you could say:

> You are trying to accomplish a Sisyphean job.

or

> Can you help me with the Sisyphean task of cleaning this dirty bathroom?

Comment: I feel cleaning a dirty bathroom should more appropriately be described as an *herculean* task ;)